# What's the path when formatting one of the OS's of a multi-OS PC?

Tags: windows-7, windows, multi-boot, format, windows-10-preview

I have both Windows 10 and Windows 7 (main) installed on this PC. Should I do something different than the usual stuff (formatting one OS PC)? Or I'm just going to format Windows 7 partition via USB stick?

**My main concern** is losing access to my other partition which is the storage, I don't care about the Windows 10 partition.

Comment: What do you want to do? If you want to keep Windows 10 and remove Windows 7, boot into Win10 and from there format the Win7 partition. You can delete the Win7 entry from the Win10 bootloader using bcdedit from the command line or something like EasyBCD. If you want to keep Win7, boot into it and format the Win10 partition. The system should continue to boot into Win7, but in case something breaks boot from a Win7 installer DVD/USB and run Startup Repair.

Comment: I'm just trying to reinstall Windows 7. But I want to know if doing it the usual way (format/reinstall Windows 7 partition via USB stick) would cause any problems accesing my storage partition. (not Windows 10)

Comment: Not if you are careful about the partition you select to install on from within Win7 setup.

Comment: Okay, so I can also just delete the Windows 10 partition?

Comment: Yes, you can do it from within Win7 setup or better still from Disk Management after Win7 is installed.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your time and the clarification.

Comment: NP, good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

Open `Disk Management` Win+R: `diskmgmt.msc` and review your partitions. Find the one which has `(...,Boot,....)` that partition has your boot section, if you are formatting it, you may loose the boot sector and will be unable to start the second OS until to repair the boot sector.

Also if your Windows 7 partition has the boot sector and you format that one, a restore with the Windows 7 DVD will not help. You need to restore the latest boot files needed, in your case from the Windows 10 DVD